# How to change image of other buttons on onClick event?

Tags: javascript, html

i am here again with a problem.

I have four buttons, when i click on button one, it changes button image from old image to new  image ok now the image is changed but if i press button 2 the image of button 2 is changed but the image of button one is same i.e new image. i want it to revert back to old image. 
here is code :

```
<input type="image" id="start" src="buttonred.png" width="50px" height="50px" onClick= "this.src='buttonblue.png'"/>
         <input type="image"  id="stop" src="buttonred.png" width="50px" height="50px" onClick="this.src='buttonblue.png'"/>
          <input type="image"  id="slow" img src="buttonred.png" width="50px" height="50px" onClick="this.src='buttonblue.png'"/>
           <input type="image" id="fast" img src="buttonred.png" width="50px" height="50px" onClick="this.src='buttonblue.png'"/>
```

Comment: i recommend you make a function to reset all te images to the first image and after change the clicked image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typed this out in notepad and tested.

It essentially searches for the string value buttonred and replaces it with buttonblue and vice versa.

```
<input type="image" id="start" src="buttonred.png" width="50px" height="50px" onClick="colorChange(this.id)"/>
<input type="image" id="stop" src="buttonred.png" width="50px" height="50px" onClick="colorChange(this.id)"/>
<input type="image" id="slow" src="buttonred.png" width="50px" height="50px" onClick="colorChange(this.id)"/>
<input type="image" id="fast" src="buttonred.png" width="50px" height="50px" onClick="colorChange(this.id)"/>

<script>

function colorChange(id) {
    var btn = document.getElementById(id);

    if (btn.src.match(/buttonred/gi) != null) {
        btn.src = btn.src.replace("buttonred.png","buttonblue.png");
    }
    else {
        btn.src = btn.src.replace("buttonblue.png","buttonred.png");
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: there is a little problem, it doesnt change the button color of other buttons, it just change its own color..

Comment: PLEASE HELP!! YOUR CODE ONLY APPLIES TO ONE BUTTON. other buttons are unffected

Comment: What browser are you using? I tested it out on firefox and chrome and it works for all the buttons.

Comment: Hi Waqar, try creating a new HTML file with only that snippet of code above and of course bind the whole thing with HTML tags. Let me know the results because I have no issues whatsoever.

Comment: Ok I will do as u said as soon as I reach home

Comment: Not sure what to tell you because it works fine on both my work computer and home computer using firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but something like this is what you're looking for:

```
(function () {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            for (var a = 0; a < elems.length; a++) {
                elems[a].src = "buttonred.png";
            }
            elems[i].src = "buttonblue.png";
        });
    }
})()
```

The key here is to have your function reset all of the images back to the original before the one that was clicked changes.